# `Run app` and `Rebuild` running different commands

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

In my project, I have 2 modules: `app` and `library`. When I run `Rebuild` in Android Studio 3.0.1, 3 gradle tasks are run:

- `clean`
- `:library:assembleDebug`
- `:app:assembleDebug`.

But if I run `Run app` after `Clean`, only `:app:assembleDebug` is run. How come `:library:assembleDebug` isn't needed? Shouldn't `Run app` run the commands of `Rebuild` without `clean`?

My `Clean` runs the following:

- clean
- :library:generateDebugSources
- :library:generateDebugAntroidTestSources
- :library:mockableAndroidJar
- :app:generateDebugSources
- :app:generateDebugAntroidTestSources
- :app:mockableAndroidJar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actions `Rebuild` and `Run app` run different gradle tasks.

The `clean` task (with the `type=delete`) deletes the build directory **when** it runs.
When you launch `Run app` the `app:clean` task is going to run while the `Rebuild` item calls the `clean` task.
In the first case it is not needed to assemble again the other modules, in your case the `library` module.

Comment: Doesn't the `clean` task delete modules as well though? If not, how should modules be deleted?

Comment: lib:clean for example. But why should you clean lib when you build app?